# On the exporting process from Mathematica in vector graphic

Tags: plotting, color, latex, rasterize, matex

### 1) Preamble: the problem

So I was trying to make a plot of the visible spectrum of the hydrogen atom and I had lot of troubles with exporting it.

First I want to point that I have to use this plot in a LaTeX document, so I needed the package [`MaTeX`](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html), which you probably need to load to run my code. Also I really need vector graphic plots, and not the rasterised version; this would lead in the following to the problem of size files.
Here's the listing.

```
(*Preamble: loading 2 packages of LaTeX and the MaTeX package for Mathematica*)
<< MaTeX`
SetOptions[MaTeX, 
  "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{color}\\usepackage{siunitx}"}];

(* rgbSpec: That's a function for making the proper ColorFunction *)

rgbSpec[x_] := RGBColor @@ Piecewise[
   {
    {
     {19/100 + 19/3000 (410 - x), 0, 1 - 6/300 (410 - x)},
     380 <= x < 410},
    {
     {19/3000 (440 - x), 0, 1},
     410 <= x < 440},
    {
     {0, 1 - (490 - x)/50, 1},
     440 <= x < 490},
    {{0, 1, (510 - x)/20},
     490 <= x < 510},
    {
     {1 - (580 - x)/70, 1, 0},
     510 <= x < 580},
    {
     {1, (640 - x)/60, 0},
     580 <= x < 640},
    {
     {1, 0, 0},
     640 <= x < 700},
    {
     {35/100 + 65/8000 (780 - x), 0, 0},
     700 <= x <= 780}
    }
   ]

myplot = Show[
   DensityPlot[x,
   {x, 380, 780},
   {y, 0, 400},
   ColorFunction -> (rgbSpec[#] &), (*Use of rgbSpec*)
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
   PlotRangePadding -> None,
   PlotRange -> {{380, 780}, {0, 400}},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameTicks -> {
     {None, None},
     {
      {
       {380, MaTeX[380], {0, 0.3}}, {420, 
        MaTeX[420, Magnification -> 1.6], {0, 0.3}},
       {460, MaTeX[460], {0, 0.3}}, {500, 
        MaTeX[500, Magnification -> 1.6], {0, 0.3}},
       {540, MaTeX[540], {0, 0.3}}, {580, 
        MaTeX[580, Magnification -> 1.6], {0, 0.3}},
       {620, MaTeX[620], {0, 0.3}}, {660, 
        MaTeX[660, Magnification -> 1.6], {0, 0.3}},
       {700, MaTeX[700], {0, 0.3}}, {740, 
        MaTeX[740, Magnification -> 1.6], {0, 0.3}},
       {780, MaTeX[780], {0, 0.3}}, {380, "", {0, 0.2}},
       {400, "", {0, 0.2}}, {420, "", {0, 0.2}},
       {440, "", {0, 0.2}}, {460, "", {0, 0.2}},
       {480, "", {0, 0.2}}, {500, "", {0, 0.2}},
       {520, "", {0, 0.2}}, {540, "", {0, 0.2}},
       {560, "", {0, 0.2}}, {580, "", {0, 0.2}},
       {600, "", {0, 0.2}}, {620, "", {0, 0.2}},
       {640, "", {0, 0.2}}, {660, "", {0, 0.2}},
       {680, "", {0, 0.2}}, {700, "", {0, 0.2}},
       {720, "", {0, 0.2}}, {740, "", {0, 0.2}},
       {760, "", {0, 0.2}}, {780, "", {0, 0.2}}
       },(* Emission wavelenghts *)
      {
       {656.2, MaTeX[656.2, Magnification -> 1.7], {0, 0.2}},
       {486.0, MaTeX["486.0", Magnification -> 1.7], {0, 0.2}}, 
       {434.0, MaTeX["434.0", Magnification -> 1.7], {0, 0.2}}, 
       {410.1, MaTeX[410.1, Magnification -> 1.7], {0, 0.2}}
       }
      }
     },
   FrameLabel -> {MaTeX[
      "\\text{Wavelenght~~}\\lambda~(\\si{\\nano\\meter})", 
      Magnification -> 2], 
     MaTeX["\\mathbf{H}~~", Magnification -> 2]},
   AspectRatio -> Full,
   ImageSize -> {1000, 200}, 
   RotateLabel -> False
   ],  
  Graphics[Rectangle[{656.2 + .5, 0}, {656.2 - .5, 400}]], 
  Graphics[Rectangle[{486.0 + .5, 0}, {486.0 - .5, 400}]], 
  Graphics[Rectangle[{434.0 + .5, 0}, {434.0 - .5, 400}]], 
  Graphics[Rectangle[{410.1 + .5, 0}, {410.1 - .5, 400}]]
 ]
```

Now the product of all this code is this image (which I just screenshoted)

[image]

Now, as the image was so far from the vector graphic that I wanted (if you full screen it you'll notice), I tried to export the image by right-clicking on the image and use the option `Save graphic as...` which lead me to the choice of the format of the image, the name and the possible options, as shown below

[image]

Now, as the default exporting options were giving me low resolution and non-vector graphic images I choose, under `Options...->Graphic containing transparency` and `Options...->Graphic containing smooth shading` the `Use Highest Quality Vector` option

[image]

which at first seemed to do exactly what I wanted but led to this strange output (when saved in PDF)

[image]

As you can see there are strange white spaces (you maybe have to enlarge it) and transversal lines in the color gradient. So now I have solved the problem of vectorial plot, but I have the problem in the color gradient defined by the `rgbSpec[x_]` function.

### 2) The body: an attempt of solution...

I thought that increasing the `PlotPoints` could have been a nice idea, so I set them at 100 (it took more than half a minute to get the output) but the result is still looking ugly with some strange white dots above my color gradient and the visible strip of the changing color

[image]

To see this effect you need eventually to open the file for full resolution image. Plus, the problem now is that I have a 22,3 MB image, which is not great if you want to put it in a TeX.

So I thought that the problem was the pdf format container, and I tried with the SVG format, with the same option  `Use Highest Quality Vector`. Sadly the result is not vector graphic at all! I really can't understand this, but opening the output with `Inkscape` or `Gapplin` it's easy to notice this fact (as above I'm now posting just a detail of the picture)

[image]

You can notice that is not vectorial because of the blur which shouldn't be there when zooming a SVG.

### 3)The end: what I ask and what I would like

I seek a vector graphic plot in PDF or SVG and a way to convert it in SVG maintaining is vectorial properties which is not 100 MB but in which the color gradient is uniform and without strange patterns.

I think that the bug is inside the `ColorFunction` which doesn't fill properly the area so when it's printed in vector graphic it is not the same as the output you see on Mathematica.

Comment: There is no need to tell us about how many days you worked on a problem, how frustrated you are, the stages of the work, etc.  This makes your problem needlessly long and discourages anyone from reading it (and thus helping you).  I think you can cut this problem down by more than 50% and urge you to do so.  I for one will not work on the problem as it stands.

Comment: Is it ok now? You were faster than me, sorry for that... I added the part 2) to avoid answers of already tried solutions, anyway if there is still something it is not appropriate let me know.